# Override function parameter type with type of derived class

Tags: c++

I plan to create an interface (rather a virtual base class in c++) with a method that takes an argument of the own type.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void seriousMethod(const Base &arg) = 0;
}
```

The derived class should however take not an argument of the base class type but of the derived class type.

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    virtual void seriousMethod(const Derived &arg) { /* ... */ }
}
```

How would I realize this? Would I have to template the base class (e.g. `Base<Derived>`) or is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: More to the point - what is the motivation to do this?

Comment: "The derived class should however take not an argument of the base class type but of the derived class type"   -- what's the point in having virtual methods at all then ?

Comment: @EdHeal To be specific, an A-Star search generic node class that is to be specified by the derived implementations.

Comment: @AdamS - What is a A-Star search?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't do this directly. Think about this case:

```
Base b;
Derived d;
Base& d_ref = d;
d_ref.seriousMethod(b);  // What happens here?
```

At compile-time, the variable `d_ref` has static type `Base`, so according to the definition of `Base`, it should be able to take `b` as a parameter to `seriousMethod`.

But at runtime, the dynamic type of `d_ref` is `Derived`, so it according to the definition of `Derived`, it can't take `b` as a parameter to `seriousMethod`. It can't convert `b` to `Derived` since it might be a straight `Base` object (if `Base` is not abstract), or it might be some other class derived from `Base` that is not the same as `Derived`.

You are correct in assuming that the only real way to go about this is the curiously-recurring template pattern, i.e. templating `Base` and defining `Derived` as:

```
class Derived : public Base<Derived> { ... }
```

This removes the problem illustrated above, because each type derived from `Base<T>` will have a distinct base class, and will not be related to one another through inheritance.